# How to save bundle data in a fragment using onPause

Tags: android

Almost every source says to persist data in onPause() instead of onSaveInstanceState() in preparation for the activity being torn down/set up again.

However, I cannot seem to find a concrete example of saving data to the bundle inside of a fragment's onPause() method. (outState is not available during onPause() method. It is only available in onSaveInstanceState().)

What code do I add to persist my page data properly to its outState using

```
override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    // ???
}
```

Comment: What sources are you looking at? The [Saving State with Fragments guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/saving-state#savedstate) does not mention that at all and very specifically points you to use `onSaveInstanceState()`.

Comment: This and others all say "...should save important information within the onPause-Method because the onsaveinstance-method is not part of the android lifecycle."

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-to-save-an-activity-state-using-save-instance-state

Comment: Please consider official resources just slightly more trustworthy than stack overflow questions from 8+ years ago.